# How does n_points in skopt BayesSearchCV work?

Tags: parallel-processing, skopt, bayessearchcv

I am confused on how does n_points work in skopt BayesSearchCV. As I understood, Bayes Search is sequential. But in skopt BayesSearchCV, we can set n_point parameter which specifies the number of parameter settings to sample in parallel. How does this parallelism work? Does it do n_points number of independent BayesSearches or does it perform batch Bayesian optimization?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/tree/master/skopt), `BayesSearchCV` is generating and trying a batch of parameter sets of size `n_points` at each step of the optimization. (see `BayesSearchCV._step` and `optimzer.ask`)

So the parameter sets in the batch are generated with the same amount of "knowledge" of param space. This trades off more quickly searching the parameter space (assuming `n_jobs` > 1) with increased risk of trying poor parameter sets.

Note that the batch size will be subtracted from the `n_iter` tally, so there becomes a distinction between number of parameter sets tried and the number of iterations of Bayes optimization. For instance if `n_iter=100` and `n_points=5` then there will be 20 rounds of optimization.